# Use folders Inside CodeIgniter Model and Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter Framework to build a php Website. I need to organize my controllers like:

`application/controller/HRModuleController/<myControllers>`
`application/controller/AccountModuleController/<myControllers>`

Can I use that way to organize my controllers and Models?

If I can how do I call the controller in the View?

```
<?php echo HRModuleController/EmployeeController/select_all ?>//is this Correct?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Controllers you can do like this, By adding a root controller inside `/application/core`

> Refer to this link -
>   http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it like that. I suggest you [first read the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/). Reading an hour in it will save you dozens.

To answer your question:
When the user clicks a link, the request will go to your controller. In your controller you call your views (and models). The way to go to the next controller is by using a link, like:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller'); ?>">Click here!</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call the controller by `$this->EmployeeContoller->select_all(arguments);`

Comment: Uhm, which version of CI? IIRC, that's wrong, but it may has well be changed in the 3.0

Comment: It is not possible to call a controller that way. It will result in a fatal error.